# Estimate of Taylor reminder for function of two variable

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \in C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}_{+}, \mathbb{R})$. In book which I'm reading is written
\begin{equation}
f(t,y) - f(s,x) = (t-s)\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s,x) + (y-x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(s,x) + r(s,t,x,y),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
|r(s,t,x,y)| \leq (y-x)^2h(x,y,s,t) + (t-s)k(x,y,s,t)
\end{equation}
and $h,k$ are bounded and uniformly continuous. How can I derive this formula?

I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(p+tv) =f(p)+ \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(p+tv)dt$$
with  $p,v\in \mathbb{R^{2}}$